# Remove 1 or multiple lines with pattern match?

Tags: text-editor

I'm trying to figure out how to edit a feeder txt file.  Previously, I had been able to accomplish this by using Word's Replace function using Wildcards.  But, the most recent feeder file seems to be too big to open in Word.  So I'm having to find some other way to replace the text.

The file looks something like this:

```
VSTHDR|data|data|data|data
...
VSTPMTH|data|1|
CRDHLDR|data|data|data
ADDR|data|data|data
VSTPMTR|data|data
VSTPMTA|data|
VSTPMTA|data
VSTPMTH|data|2|
CRDHLDR|data|data|data
VSTPMTR|data|data
VSTPMTH|data|3|
VSTPMTR|data|data
VSTPMTA|data
...
VST...
...
ADDR|data|data|data
```

and repeat.  For all but the last VSTPMTH, there is always a CRDHLDR line. Under CRDHLDR, there may or may not be an ADDR line.  Then there is always a VSTPMTR.  There may or may not be VSTPMTA lines.  There will be more lines that start with VST before finally ending with another ADDR line before the next VSTHDR.

My goal is to remove all CRDHLDR lines, and any ADDR lines that immediately follow them.  In Word, I was able to use replace all "CRDHLDR*VSTPMTR" with "VSTPMTR".

I thought I had it with

```
sed '/CRDHLDR/,/^[^V]/d'
```

but with that, if there wasn't an ADDR line immediately after, it would delete all of the VST lines following.

Another idea I had was to try taking any line that starts with ADDR and add it to the line before it, and then go back through to delete any CRDHLR lines, and then add a newline back in before any remaining ADDR.  However, all the scripts I've found for combining lines seem to be restricted by a hold buffer size, which this file quickly exceeds. If you can think of a set of commands to try that maybe reduces the buffer use, I'll happily try it.

The closest I've been able to come to a solution so far has been to run:

```
sed '/CRDHLDR/,/VSTPMTR/d'
```

but that removes VSTPMTR which I don't want to delete.  If I could get that to delete all but the last line of that selection (instead of the whole selection), that would be PERFECT.

I haven't seen any grep or awk solutions that seem quite right, but I'm willing to try any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a two step answer:

```
sed '/CRDHLDR/,/VSTPMTR/ {ADDR/d}'
sed '/CRDHLDR/d'
```

The first line removes ADDR lines that are between CRDHLDR and VSTPMTR, the second line then removes all CRDHLDR lines.